# onReceive method on SwiftUI view won’t execute for a custom publisher

Tags: swiftui, onchange, publisher

In my app, I use the `onChange()` method and a publisher to detect and notify of available screen width change. Also I use the `innerWorkInProgress` published property in my view model to control view's opacity. The view’s opacity is set to 0 on screen width change. Once content of the view has been updated, its opacity is set back to 1 in the `onAppear()` method.
My problem is that the `onReceive()` method won’t execute if I set the value to `innerWorkInProgress` in the `onChange()` method.
If I use a state variable instead of the published property, the `onReceive()` method works well.

What’s wrong with my code?

Below is a simplified reproducible example. You can test it by rotating your device from portrait to landscape and vice versa.

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                MyView(viewModel: viewModel)
                Spacer()
                Text("Another view")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hey!", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

MyView

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State private var initFlag = false
    
    let widthChangeDetector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    let widthChangePublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        
        let wDetector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.widthChangePublisher = wDetector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.widthChangeDetector = wDetector
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                // ForEach along with the viewModel.jIndex published property creates 
                // a new instance of Text view every time viewModel.jIndex is updated.
                // In this way, we can make use of Text's onAppear on each instance newly created.
                ForEach((viewModel.jIndex-1..<viewModel.jIndex), id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(viewModel.textData)
                        .id(viewModel.jIndex)
                        .opacity(viewModel.innerWorkInProgress ? 0 : 1)
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                viewModel.innerWorkInProgress = false
                            }
                        }
                        .onChange(of: geometry.size.width) { newWidth in
                            if !initFlag {
                                initFlag = true
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // Problem: this line prevents onReceive from executing
                            viewModel.innerWorkInProgress = true
                            
                            widthChangeDetector.send(newWidth)
                        }
                        .onReceive(widthChangePublisher) { finalWidth in
                            print("onReceive, FINAL WIDTH = \(finalWidth)")
                            Task {
                                await viewModel.loadData()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.loadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
import Foundation

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var innerWorkInProgress = false
    @Published private(set) var jIndex = 0
    private(set) var textData = ""
    
    func loadData() async {
        innerWorkInProgress = true
        let i = jIndex + 1
        textData = "#\(i) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
        jIndex = i
    }
}
```

Here is an alternative version of MyView, with the `onChangeEventInProgress` state property being used instead of the published property. This version works without any problems.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    // a state property used instead of a published property
    @State private var onChangeEventInProgress = false
    @State private var initFlag = false
    
    let widthChangeDetector: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    let widthChangePublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never>
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        
        let wDetector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
        self.widthChangePublisher = wDetector
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        self.widthChangeDetector = wDetector
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach((viewModel.jIndex-1..<viewModel.jIndex), id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(viewModel.textData)
                        .id(viewModel.jIndex)
                        .opacity(onChangeEventInProgress ? 0 : 1)
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                onChangeEventInProgress = false
                            }
                        }
                        .onChange(of: geometry.size.width) { newWidth in
                            if !initFlag {
                                initFlag = true
                                return
                            }
                            // This line doesn't cause any problems
                            onChangeEventInProgress = true

                            widthChangeDetector.send(newWidth)
                        }
                        .onReceive(widthChangePublisher) { finalWidth in
                            print("onReceive, FINAL WIDTH = \(finalWidth)")
                            Task {
                                await viewModel.loadData()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.loadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `onReceive` does not depend on cycle `i`, and you don't need it more that one, so try to attach it outside of `ScrollView`

Comment: @Asperi I had already tried that out. I had tried out different variations, for example both onChange and onReceive outside of ScrollView. Result is the same--onReceive is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move the GeometryReader block outside of NavigationView. As a result, the onChange() method is called just once on a descendant view. This allows getting rid of widthChangeDetector, widthChangePublisher, and the onReceive(widthChangePublisher) method at all.

Below is the modified code.

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    MyView(geometryProxy: geometry, viewModel: viewModel)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Another view")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Hey!", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

MyView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    private var geometryProxy: GeometryProxy
    
    init(geometryProxy: GeometryProxy, viewModel: ViewModel){
        self.geometryProxy = geometryProxy
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // ForEach along with the viewModel.jIndex published property creates
            // a new instance of Text view every time viewModel.jIndex is updated.
            // In this way, we can make use of Text's onAppear on each instance newly created.
            ForEach(((viewModel.jIndex == 0 ? 0 : viewModel.jIndex-1)..<viewModel.jIndex), id: \.self) { i in
                Text(viewModel.textData)
                    .id(i)
                    .opacity(viewModel.innerWorkInProgress ? 0 : 1)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                            viewModel.innerWorkInProgress = false
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await viewModel.loadData()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: geometryProxy.size.width) { newWidth in
            viewModel.innerWorkInProgress = true
            
            Task {
                await viewModel.loadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```